# Ansible regex replace String

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying to replace the unnecessary words from the below string using regex_replace but unable to do to so for the last part of it.

```
String: Test_[u'Net::Route Domain: RD2001']

Regex being used: regex_replace('.*: (.*)$', '\\1') 
Output printing: Test_RD2001']

Expected Output: Test_RD2001
```

Could someone suggest how can I get rid of the last characters after RDXXXX.
Also this RDXXXX number is dynamic.

Comment: `u'Net::Route Domain: RD2001'` is suspicious looking. How does this string get built in the first place, because it looks like python printing an internal representation of a unicode string rather than normal string variable contents, or `[]` looks like you are printing an array containing the string `Net::Route...` as a string itself

Comment: Actually it is an output from an "item.stdout_lines[0]" which I am logging into a file using blockinfile module. Not sure from where these crazy characters getting appended.  Ideally the output I get is "Net::Route Domain: RD2001" and I a just need RD2001 value.

Comment: @P.... Thanks alot yes it worked. I mark as accept

Comment: @P.... could u tell me what exactly does this part of regexp does.. '^(\\w+)

Comment: Put these comments below the answer to contact the answerer - but `^` matches the start of the string so nothing comes before, and \w+ matches one or more "word characters", non-whitespace, non-punctuation, so together they match and capture the word `Test_` at the start of the string, before the first `[u'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dicussed in comments, you should try to fix the data source. However, here is the regex to print the expected result:

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  #gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    String: "Test_[u'Net::Route Domain: RD2001']"
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ String| regex_replace('^(\\w+)\\[.*:\\s+([\\w]+).*', '\\1\\2') }}"
```

Results:

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Test_RD2001"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```